# 3rd conditional plus 2nd conditional?

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditionals

"If you **had seen** him as a child, you **would** agree that he is extraordinary."

In this sentence, changing the past perfect to simple past strikes me as wrong, and changing the "would agree" to "would have agreed" also strikes me as wrong. But what I'm left with is something that looks like a hybrid conditional. Basically, the first part of the sentence talks about **then**, and the second talks about **now**.

I would like to know whether this sentence is grammatical to begin with, and if it is, whether conditional sentences must **always** be expressed as on of the three types of conditionals.

Comment: This is perfectly valid. It is saying that if you had seen him as a child in the past, you would agree now that he is extraordinary now.

Comment: See the referenced paper in my comment to Barrie for sound reason to disabuse oneself of all this “Nᵗʰ Conditional” nonsense that gets shoved down people’s throats. It’s a synthetic device (or perhaps better put, a harmful fabulation)  that just doesn’t work for real English corpora.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've always thought that that these Nth conditional things greatly restricted expression. :)

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Answer (score 2):

If you had seen him as a child, you would agree that he is extraordinary.

This is a mixed Conditional.  It is not the 3rd Conditional.

3rd Conditional: - The third conditional is used to talk about things which DID NOT HAPPEN in the past.

If you HAD SEEN him as a child, you WOULD HAVE AGREED (then at some point in the past) that he is extraordinary.

Mixed Conditional: -

If you HAD SEEN him as a child, you WOULD AGREE (now at this point) that he is extraordinary

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine. Ignore the nonsense about "2nd conditionals" etc and then the sentence won't look problematic any more.

Comment: Yes, the customary division of conditionals into three categories, plus the present conditional, is an artificial device, which fails to capture many of the variations actually found. Nevertheless, it is a helpful simplification for foreign learners, and it is in that context only that it is normally used.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Indeed so.  Obligatory reference to “If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals” by Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, published in *ELT Journal* Volume 65/1 January 2011 (Oxford University Press); doi:10.1093/elt/ccp101

Comment: I'm still curious about this and other "sequence of tense" malarkey in the teaching material of other languages: overall, is its error rate actually lower than if you just use the rule "use the tense that you would expect to use"?

Answer (score -1):

Now that Shoe has educated me on what the 3 conditionals are, I can say for sure that no, it is not true that "conditional sentences must always be expressed as one of the three types of conditionals."  [Mixing is allowed](http://www.englishpage.com/conditional/mixedconditional.html).

Your sentence *"If you had seen him as a child, you would agree that he is extraordinary"* is perfectly fine English.  David Schwartz is exactly right when he says it  is saying that if you had seen him as a child in the past, you would agree now that he is extraordinary now.

There is no problem with the first part of the sentence referring to the past while the second part refers to the present.

Comment: Conditional 1: *I will be happy if she comes*. Conditional 2: *I would be happy if she came*. Conditional 3: *I would have been happy if she had come*. But native speakers often mix these up for all kinds of reasons. Hybrid conditionals are far from rare and are not ungrammatical.

Comment: @Shoe, Thank you for spelling out the 3 conditionals. Can you tell me where _I would be happy if she were coming to my party_ fits in?

Comment: Conditional 2 can refer to the (contrafactual) present or to the future. Present: *If I were you, I would ..* (but I am not you). Your party sentence fits in here because you know in the present that she is not coming. Future: *I would be happy if she came*. (You don't know whether she will come. You will be happy if she does but you regard it as unlikely.)

Comment: Don’t believe in all this Nᵗʰ Conditional bogosity.  It’s been shown to be just so much rubbish.

Comment: @tchrist, Pedagogic grammars for non-native learners of English traditionally introduce the conditional by differentiating between the 3 basic tense combinations and their associated meanings (for example, *Cambridge Grammar of English*, 2006, p748). These combinations do indeed reflect very common patterns in English syntax, and as such are helpful for beginning learners to master. The terms give teachers a shorthand way to refer to these patterns. What is unhelpful is when learners then erroneously believe that these are the only combinations possible, as seems to be the case with the OP.

Comment: @Shoe [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks. Interesting article. My point is that many pedagogic grammars designate a common subset of _if-sentences_ as _zero, first, second and third conditionals_. And I agree with Swan (Practical English Grammar, p233) that: "_These are useful structures to practise_."  It is clearly a problem, however, if students are left to believe that these are the only possibilities, and it may be that the very designation leads some learners to make this assumption.